# How to perform silent installation using git bash

Tags: command-line, git-bash, silent-installer

I am using git bash to perform installation of exe file.
    my git bash located into below location 
    C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe 
    I opened that bash.exe and try to install my exe as below 
    $ ./Setup.exe /silent

```
But it still popup me for user indirection during installation .

and same command is working fine if I will execute using C:\cygwin64
```

Comment: git is a not a deployment tool.

Comment: yes, bt when I used Bash task of azure devOps its automatically using Git Bash